# Groovy script compiles to a class

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, closures

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679712/3317808), I learnt that, every Groovy script compiles to a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script` class

Below is a test groovy script written for Jenkins pipeline in Jenkins editor.

```
node('worker_node'){
    print "***1. DRY principle***"

    def list1 = [1,2,3,4]
    def list2 = [10,20,30,40]

    def factor = 2

    def applyFactor =  {e -> e * factor}

    print(list1.each(applyFactor))
    print(list2.each(applyFactor))



    print "***2. Higher order function***"

    def foo = { value, f ->  f(value *2) }

    foo(3, {print "Value is $it"})

    foo(3){
        print "Value is $it"
    }
}
```

---

How to compile this groovy script to see the class generated(source code)?

Answer (score 1):

The class generated is *bytecode*, not source code. The source code is the Groovy script.

If you want to see something similar to what the equivalent Java source code would look like, use [`groovyc`](http://groovy-lang.org/groovyc.html#section-groovyc-compiler) to compile the script as usual, and then use a Java decompiler to produce Java source ([this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) lists a few).

That's subject to the usual caveats on decompiled code, of course. High-level information is lost in the process of compiling. Decompilers have to guess a bit to figure out the best way to represent what might have been in the original source. For instance, what was a `for` loop in the original code may end up being decompiled as a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

groovy in jenkins pipeline is a Domain Specific Language. 
It's not a plain groovy.

However if you remove `node(){  }` then it seems to be groovy in your case.

and you can run it in `groovyconsole` or compile to class with `groovyc`

just download a stable [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) binary and extract it.

if you have java7 or java8 on your computer - you can run groovyconsole and try your code there.

with `Ctrl+T` you can see the actual class code generated for your script.

Comment: Aah.. so groovy running within `node(){}` is not same as groovy scripting compiled to subclass of `Script` class?

Comment: no. pipeline runs own interpreter. based on groovy but different )

Comment: Is this the reason, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742341/3317808) solution not working?